# Clone array of objects Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I need to create a clone of an array of objects in Crystal.

`cloned_person_array = persons.clone #[Person, Person, Person]`

But I get the following error:

`undefined method 'clone' for Person
Array(T).new(size) { |i| @buffer[i].clone.as(T) }`

I realized that this method is not meant for non-primitives that are defined by the code. The [documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.2/Array.html#clone-instance-method) doesn't explicitly exclude it, but it does only show a primitive example.

**How do you clone an array of objects in Crystal?**

I can imagine performing a `.map` on the array and then returning a new array that way, but  I'm curious if maybe I'm just using the clone method mentioned above incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define `Person#clone` yourself, to allow you to clone `Array(Person)`.

An easy way to do this is the [`def_clone`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/Object.html#def_clone-macro) macro.

```
class Person
  property name : String

  def_clone
end
```

Comment: Ah, I had tried creating a clone function in the method but it failed since I didn't understand it needed property information. So I assume that for each property that needs to be cloned that you would need another param? like if you had property address, you'd need def_clone name, address?

Comment: That is correct. The arguments to def_clone is a list of instance variables which must be cloned. With no args you just get a copy of the object (same as dup)

Comment: It looks like you do not need to include a list of variables anymore. It will throw an error if you try to. Just includingthee macro  def_clone in your class is enough